# How to link an equation in LaTeX

Tags: hyperref, equations, cross-referencing

I am wondering how I can link an equation in LaTeX, I mean when I click on the link then I'll be directed to that specific equation.

Comment: I recommend you to take a look at the book LaTeX on WikiBooks which covers many of these basic questions. The following part fits your needs: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use the standard `\label{key}`, `\ref{key}` (or, if `amsmath` has been loaded, `\eqref{key}` to automatically include the parenthesis in the reference) mechanism; `\label` assigns a "key" (a string of characters and/or digits and/or punctuation) to the element (a sectioning command, one of the environments `equation`, `figure`, `table`, the theorem-like structures, etc.); `\ref` typesets the "number" associated to the key. There's also `\pageref{key}` to typeset the number of the page where the `\label` command was used.

The [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package will automatically generate customizable hyperlinks in your document.

A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:test}
  a=b
\end{equation}
\eqref{eq:test}

\end{document}
```

You'll have to compile twice to generate the cross-references.

Comment: The OP wants a clickable link. So the `hyperref` package is required in addition.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: you are right, I'll add the `hyperref` package to my answer.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina thanks so much. how i can change the color of hyper-linked equation from red to green?

Comment: @MON: you can use `\usepackage{xcolor}\hypersetup{linkbordercolor=green}`. The hyperref documentation (follow the link in my answer) explains many other options; here is a summary of the available options: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/options.pdf

Comment: There's a small typo in your answer : you type \eqre{key} instead of \eqref{key}

Comment: @Frédéric Grosshans: I don't see any typo... ah, now I see it (I looked only at the code). I will correct it; thank you very much.

Comment: @Gonzalo: Your answer start with :"You can use the standard \label{key}, \ref{key} (or, if amsmath has been loaded, \eqre{key} ..." . Just before the dots, you use eqre{} while you use eqre*f*{} in the code example.

Answer (score 8):

you need to use an environment -- like `equation` or many of the environments in `amsmath` -- that can be numbered and take a `\label`.  then using the `hyperref` package and `\ref{`*label-value*`}` (or, better, `amsmath`'s `\eqref`) there will be hyperlinks in your pdf output.

Comment: Does this work also for a beamer presentation with slides?

Comment: @Alessandro -- I'm sorry, I don't know whether it works for `beamer`, and am unable to experiment now.  But I think it's worth a try.