# referencing a line in a proof

Tags: cross-referencing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to link an equation in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-to-link-an-equation-in-latex)

I have the following mathematical statement:

```
\begin{equation}
\forall_{\epsilon > 0} \exists_{N_2} \text{  such that  } n>N_2 \implies |m_n^- - 0| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{equation}
```

Suppose this statement is labeled `(1)` by `\begin{equation}`. How can I quickly reference this without typing "`(1)`"? I would like to say something in my proof like: by `(1)` this is true.

Is there a way to label and then reference these labels?

Comment: See if this answers your question. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-to-link-an-equation-in-latex Disregard the `hyperref` for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be, using the `amsmath` package and `\eqref` (and `\label` of course). Here is an MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:myformular}
    \forall_{\epsilon > 0} \exists_{N_2} \text{  such that  } n>N_2 \implies |m_n^- - 0| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{equation}

See for example \eqref{eq:myformular}

\end{document}
```

Which produces
[image: eqref example]

I used a usual naming scheme (`eq:something`) to know from the name of the label, that it refers to an equation. That way you don't have to look up, whether the label refers to the lemma or the eqaution (using of course `lem:something` as labels for lemmas)

Comment: Check out my related post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86338/label-one-line-in-a-begin-align for a similar question please.

Comment: Well, @Werner answered the related post - and indeed also this one (by using also `eqref` in his answer)