# Label one line in align* environment

Tags: cross-referencing, align

I have the following block of TeX:

```
\begin{align*}
m_n^+ = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{n} =& \dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{n}\left(a_k-L+L\right) \\
                                            <& \dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}+L\right) \\
                                            <& \dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}+L\right) = \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}+L \\
\end{align*}
```

How could I set a label for the last line in this block so that I may reference it later?

Comment: Note your use of `align`'s alignments are incorrect. You need `&=` and `&<`, *not* `=&` and `<&`.

Comment: @Werner Or `={}&` and `<{}&` could be used to get the spacing right. Also the latest `\\` should be removed to avoid an empty equation line.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can either `\tag` the line in an (unnumbered) `align*` or `\nonumber` each equation you don't want in a (numbered) `align`. Here's a snapshot of both:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
m_n^+ = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{n} &= \dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{n}\left(a_k-L+L\right) \\
                                            &< \dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}+L\right) \\
                                            &< \dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}+L\right) = \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}+L 
                                              \stepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}\label{myeq1}\\
\end{align*}
See~\eqref{myeq1}.

\begin{align}
m_n^+ = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{n} &= \dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{n}\left(a_k-L+L\right) \nonumber \\
                                            &< \dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}+L\right) \nonumber \\
                                            &< \dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}+L\right) = \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}+L \label{myeq2}
\end{align}
See~\eqref{myeq2}.
\end{document}
```

The approach depends on the ease of use, or perhaps the size (number/quantity) of the set of the equations.

The former `\tag`-method uses the same counter (`equation`), although it requires manually stepping. In both instances, `\label` works as usual to capture the number for later use through `\eqref`.

Answer (score 8):

The best way to treat this, which is *one* equation in more lines is with `split`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{nice}
\begin{split}
m_n^+ = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N+1}^{n}
  &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N+1}^{n}(a_k-L+L) \\
  &< \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N+1}^{n}\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2}+L\right) \\
  &< \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2}+L\right) = \frac{\epsilon}{2}+L 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
See~\eqref{nice}.

\end{document}
```

The default placement of the equation number is centered on the whole equation, as in the example; if one says

```
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}
```

then the equation number will be aligned with the top or bottom row, according to whether numbers are at the left or the right margin.

Notice that I've removed the useless `\limits` commands (and also a `\left`-`\right` pair that's wrong). Also `\dfrac` can be `\frac`, because we are in a display.

[image]

Comment: The `[t]` and `[b]` options work with `split` or they do not? Because I usually prefer the number to be at the last line...

Comment: @tohecz With the `tbtags` option the number will be at the last line, provided the equation number is on the right. It would have little sense putting the number at the last line with equation numbers at the left.