# Reference equation in text latex

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I am trying to reference labeled equations in a document but I am unsure if how to compile twice. Upon the first compilation I get (??)  where all my references are. I followed this link: 
[How to link an equation in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-to-link-an-equation-in-latex).
I am using TeXworks on a MAC.

Comment: If you're able to compile, can you compile again yet you receive the same `??`?

Comment: @user38771 I suggest you use `latexmk` if you don't want to worry about compiling twice, or even thrice.

Answer (score 1):

All that compiling twice means is that you basically need to run

```
latex latex_source_code.tex
latex latex_source_code.tex
```

or

```
pdflatex latex_source_code.tex
pdflatex latex_source_code.tex
```

in the shell somehow.

If you ever get into bibliographies you will need to run something like

```
pdflatex latex_source_code.tex
bibtex latex_source_code.aux
pdflatex latex_source_code.tex
pdflatex latex_source_code.tex
```

This is all that running twice (or four times) means.  How you place these commands into the shell depends on your editor/IDE.  For TeXworks, this means you'll either have to manually click on the typeset button multiple times, sometimes switching processing tools in the dropdown menu, or use some kind of automation tool like arara (my favorite) or latexmk or rubber.

No matter what you choose, this should eliminate the `??`